# How can I list modified files first before folders?

Tags: files, filemanager, 16.10

I am trying to achieve the following listing. Recently modified files should be listed before folders.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Open your `open file` dialogue window and right click on the `name` sorting bar, in that menu that opens is an option `sort folders before files`, uncheck this

[image]

Comment: I did it but it doesn't affect the "Open File" dialog that is shown in my screenshot above.

Comment: Please try the updated answer.